# problems running state machine examples

Tags: spring-statemachine

Congratulations on the spring state machine, I found it yesterday and have been trying it out, specifically the turnstile example running in STS. I found it very easy and intuitive to build a FSM.

Because spring shell doesn't work well in STS I tracked down the instructions to run the examples from the command line in the reference doc,

> "java -jar
>   spring-statemachine-samples-turnstile-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar"

, 
but running it got an error

> > "no main manifest attribute, in spring-statemachine-samples-turnstile-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar".

Although not even a novice in using gradle, I tried fixing this by adding this line to build.gradle in the jar section

> > "manifest.attributes['Main-Class'] = 'demo.turnstile.Application'" 
> >     (which doesn't handle the various sub-projects I know) but got this error 
> >     "NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/shell/Bootstrap".

If it is possible to run the samples from gradle, could you include them in the reference document? I tried running the samples using

> > gradle run 
> >     but it there was no interaction with the shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Samples are designed to be run as executable jar and with shell so that you can interact without a need to recompile with every change. Your error indicates that you didn't build that sample jar as mentioned in docs.

```
./gradlew clean build -x test
```

This will automatically use spring boot plugin which will add the necessary jar manifest headers to jar meta info to make it a true executable jar. Essentially every every sample is a spring boot app.

Comment: Thank you so much @Janne , the [github link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine#compile-and-test-build-all-jars-distribution-zips-and-docs) needs a update.

Answer (score 0):

Building [SM sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine) projects in **Windows Environment**:

1. Open Command prompt `(windows key + r -->cmd-->Enter)`, Change directory to project root folder `spring-statemachine-master` (Inside the Extracted folder).
2. Run `gradlew install` to get all spring dependencies copied to local machine.
3. Run `gradlew clean build -x test` to get the spring shell jars built. Courtesy [Janne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3737429/janne-valkealahti)

These steps should ideally get all `.jar` built, look into `\build\libs` folder of respective sample project for jar files.

Run the like any other java jar file `java -jar [jar-file-name.jar]` (make sure to be change directory to jar file directory location).

One more thing where I was stuck was, How to give events to SM:
It's like this `sm event EVENT_NAME_AS_DEFINED_IN_CLASS`. [Ref](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#statemachine-examples-washer)
E.g.: `sm event RINSE` --> to `washer` project

Comment: The install step fails for me on a Windows

`C...>gradlew install
> Task :spring-statemachine-samples-common:spring-statemachine-samples-cdplayer:install FAILED

   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':spring-statemachine-samples-common:spring-statemachine-samples-cdplayer:install'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > Cannot publish artifact 'spring-statemachine-samples-cdplayer.jar' (C:\***\cdplayer\build\libs\spring-statemachine-samples-cdplayer-3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar) as it does not exist

BUILD FAILED in 4s`